# register rsync in shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

What should I add so that my little script logs the rsync command only if it contains files to copy and is not every 5 minutes logging nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Sincronizar directorios de Transferencia.

#Local
ORIGEN=/home/sftp/Recepcion/
DESTINO=/mnt/Recepcion/

Fecha_Y_Hora=`date "+%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S"`
RUTA_LOG="/opt/rundeck/commands/rsync.txt"

echo "[$Fecha_Y_Hora] Comenzando Sincronizacion ..." >> $RUTA_LOG
rsync -vr --times $ORIGEN $DESTINO >> $RUTA_LOG
```

Greetings

Comment: You can use `set -x`

Comment: @jordanm How does that help with what gets written to `$RUTA_LOG`?

Comment: You could use `rsync -n` and save the output to a variable. Then check if the variable contains any files to be copied. If so, skip the real `rsync`.

Comment: Please translate the title to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for files you can try something like this:

```
rsync -avunc --delete $ORIGEN $DESTINO | grep "^deleting" | wc -l
```

If the result is greater than 0, there are files.